# Set resValue independently of buildType or productFlavor?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Is there a way to use `resValue` independently of, i. e. outside of, any `buildType` or `productFlavor`?

I have some String resources in my Android project that I would like to create from within my `build.gradle` which don't vary with either build type or product flavor. For example, the following line stores the hash of the current git commit so that it can displayed in the settings

```
resValue "string", "source_git_hash", gitHash
```

I found that I can use the `all` block in either the `buildTypes` or the `productFlavors` block but this way, everything is still executed once for each build type/product flavor.

Is there a way to write the resource value globally, just once for all builds?

Comment: Does it work in `defaultConfig`?

Comment: Ah, yes it does - thanks a lot! I am not sure though that my post qualifies as "egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended"...

Comment: I didn't downvote you -- somebody else did.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying - it all happened so quickly that I thought it had to be the same person. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`defaultConfig` allows you to set the same sorts of things globally that you can do no a per-product-flavor basis. So, put your `resValue` and `buildConfigField` statements in there, to define the defaults to be used for all build variants.